# Change cell color if state is complete/in progress/not started

Tags: google-sheets, cell-formatting

I need to format the store number depending on the state where it's located. another tab shows the state status. Green for Complete/ Orange for In Progress and Yellow for Not Started. I would appreciated it if you would show me how to do it since I have a lot of files that needs to be setup that way as well. Thanks!

Here's the google sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gw9PEkrMxOVbOObwCjwtkR3x0ATpJCfUIc4nhAFfj1g/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[You may try](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gw9PEkrMxOVbOObwCjwtkR3x0ATpJCfUIc4nhAFfj1g/edit#gid=1975685260):*

***Conditional Formatting Rules***

*Apply to range:* `A2:B`

*Custom Formula is:*  `=vlookup($B2,indirect("'State status'!A:B"),2,)="Complete"`

[image]

Comment: You have a preceding blank space situation for two of your statuses: "  + CE-Only" and "  School Only" but in the conditional formatting rules you omitted the space; so the mismatch. Either have that preceding space thing in both the status part and conditional formatting OR remove it in both the situations.

Answer (score 0):

I added a copy of "store" page to your linked sheet and added the conditional formatting. What I suggest is using VLOOKUP formula

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, 'State status'!A:B, 2, FALSE)
```

to add status from the "status" page, and use "custom formula" in conditional formatting to change the color of the store number depending on this status, e.g.:

`=C2:C="Complete"`,

where "C" is the added "Status" column.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It worked only when I did the first rule. The second and 3rd rule seems to not work